# Tasker, how to append a string to a variable

Tags: tasker

Tasker is making this simple task complicated.

I am doing a "Send Intent" action within a task and I need the extra 1 and extra 2 to be a string concatenated to a number variable concatenated to another string.

In most languages it'd be something like

```
extra1 = "str1:" + integer + "str2"
```

It'd be easier if there were spaces between the strings; it'd just be `str1 %integer str2`, but there are no spaces to separate things out.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: In which language does Tasker "scripts" work?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Tasker scripts are Tasker's own special language.

Comment: @DanHulme Oh, I see. Then I can't help, sorry.

Comment: I found that Tasker supports javascript snippets, I opted to do most of my coding in that. Tasker's coding setup is painful at best.

Answer (score 1):

Set a new variable with `To` field as `%var1%var2%anyvarname`